# Line Chart Apache POI (4.1.1) - How to get rid of the Marker

Tags: apache-poi, linechart

I am currently trying to get rid of the marker on my line chart and I think I found the place to do it, but I don´t know what to pass (or better how to pass: "none".
When I extract the excel I find the following changed:

```
<c:marker>
<c:symbol val="none"/>
</c:marker>
```

I assume I should do something like this:

```
ctLineSer.addNewMarker().addNewSymbol().setVal( ???)// how to pass none?
```

But the shown options don´t tell my how I should pass none?
Here´s the full code:

```
 private void addLineToChart(String lineChartDataFormulaString, byte[] color, CTChart ctChart, CTPlotArea ctPlotArea, String labelsRefer) {
        CTScaling ctScaling;
        //val Right Axis
        CTLineChart ctLineChart = ctPlotArea.addNewLineChart();
        ctLineChart.addNewVaryColors().setVal(false); // setVaryColors(false);
        CTLineSer ctLineSer = ctLineChart.addNewSer();
        CTSerTx ctSerTx1 = ctLineSer.addNewTx();
        CTStrRef ctStrRef1 = ctSerTx1.addNewStrRef();
        ctStrRef1.setF("\"Actual Forecast\"");
        ctLineSer.addNewIdx().setVal(2); //2= Color Grey => will be overwritten, but is necessary to have no error => TODO fix that
        CTAxDataSource ctAxDataSource1 = ctLineSer.addNewCat();
        ctStrRef1 = ctAxDataSource1.addNewStrRef();
        ctStrRef1.setF(labelsRefer);
        CTBoolean ctBoolFalse = CTBoolean.Factory.newInstance();
        ctBoolFalse.setVal(false);
        ctLineSer.addNewSmooth().setVal(false);

        // TRYING TO GET RID OF MARKER
        ctLineSer.addNewMarker().addNewSymbol().setVal(???);// how to pass none?
//        ctPlotArea.getLineChartArray(0).setMarker(ctBoolFalse); //TODO: not working
//        ctLineChart.setMarker(ctBoolFalse);//TODO: not working

        //Set the colour of the line connecting points
        colorLineChartLine(color, ctLineSer);

        CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource1 = ctLineSer.addNewVal();
        CTNumRef ctNumRef1 = ctNumDataSource1.addNewNumRef();
        ctNumRef1.setF(lineChartDataFormulaString);

        //Axis
        ctLineChart.addNewAxId().setVal(1234);//id of the cat axis
        ctLineChart.addNewAxId().setVal(12345);

        CTCatAx ctCatAx1 = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx();
        ctCatAx1.addNewAxId().setVal(1234);// id of the cat Axis
        ctScaling = ctCatAx1.addNewScaling();
        ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
        ctCatAx1.addNewDelete().setVal(true);
        ctCatAx1.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.R);
        ctCatAx1.addNewCrossAx().setVal(12345); //id of the val axis

        CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx();
        ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(12345); //id of the val axis
        ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
        ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
        ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
        ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.R);
        ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(1234); //id of the cat axis
        ctValAx.addNewMinorTickMark().setVal(STTickMark.NONE);
        ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);
//        ctValAx.addNewCrosses().setVal(STCrosses.MAX); //TODO try to use the primary axis

        //Legend
        CTLegend ctLegend = ctChart.addNewLegend();
        ctLegend.addNewLegendPos().setVal(STLegendPos.B);
        ctLegend.addNewOverlay().setVal(false);
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code does it:

```
ctLineSer.addNewMarker().addNewSymbol().setVal(STMarkerStyle.NONE);
```